# Creating a view in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, view, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables:

- `Contracts` (ContactID, ContractNo, estimatedCost, CurrencyEstimatedCostID, ContractCost, CurrencyContractCostID)
- `CurrencyTypes` (CurrencyID, CurrencyTypeName).

I want to view the contract table with `CurrencyTypeName` in place of the Foreign Keys `CurrencyEstimatedCostID` and `CurrencyContractCostID` in the view (in the SQL Server view).

I use this query but it return just one column for `CurrencyTypeName` (I want one column for each of `CurrencyEstimatedCostID` and `CurrencyContractCostID`).

```
SELECT 
    Contracts.contractID, Contracts.ContractNo, CurrencyTypes.CurrencyType
FROM 
    Contracts 
INNER JOIN 
    CurrencyTypes ON Contracts.CurrencyEstimatedCostID = CurrencyTypes.CurrencyType 
                     AND Contracts.CurrencyContractCostID = CurrencyTypes.CurrencyType
```

How do I change the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure if I understand what you're trying to do - but if you have two columns that both act as foreign key into the `CurrencyTypes` table, you need to join twice:

```
SELECT 
    c.contractID, c.ContractNo, 
    EstimatedCostCurrency = ct1.CurrencyType, 
    ContractCostCurrency = ct2.CurrencyType
FROM 
    Contracts  c
INNER JOIN 
    CurrencyTypes ct1 ON c.CurrencyEstimatedCostID = ct1.CurrencyID
INNER JOIN 
    CurrencyTypes ct2 ON c.CurrencyContractCostID = ct2.CurrencyID
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be join to CurrencyId rather than CurrencyType?

Comment: @TienDinh: yes, most likely - the original question had this join condition, but that really doesn't make any sense, you're right